# PHPunit not working in 'artisan tinker' in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm doing [a tutorial on Laracast](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/22?autoplay=true) to learn Laravel. Now I'm kind of stuck on one part which I don't want to skip (first 40 seconds).

The problem is when I open PHP artisan tinker and do the command: phpunit (or vendor/bin/phpunit) it gives me the error:

```
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant phpunit - assumed 'phpunit' in /var/www/vhosts/web-wings.nl/roylar.web-wings.nleval()'d code on line 1
```

and

```
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant vendor - assumed 'vendor' in /var/www/vhosts/web-wings.nl/roylar.web-wings.nleval()'d code on line 1
```

Also when I try

```
phpunit tests/Unit/ExampleTest.php
```

It gives the error:

> PHP Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected T_STRING on line 1

So there's definitely something wrong with phpunit but I can't find the answer. I looked into the tutorial's comments, Youtube and Google but nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nothing wrong with phpunit you just test without using `php artisan tinker` 
because the tinker command uses the `PsySH` library to setup a `REPL (read-eval print loop)` environment within the context of your Laravel application